# Найти совпадение выражения в строке

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Есть разные строки, в них нужно найти совпадение выражения по маске:

строковая переменная_4цифры-2цифры-2цифры

```
str1 = 'NUMBER_2021-05-01_5690_LOCK'
str2 = 'NUMBER_OVER_2021-02-01_2100_LOCK'

str_find = 'NUMBER'

re.search(f'{str_find}_\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}', str1)
```

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А не то здесь вот что:

```
print(f'{str_find}_\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}')
```

Вывод:

```
NUMBER_\d4-\d2-\d2
```

У вас `f-строка`, поэтому фигурные скобки все исчезли - подставились значения из скобок. Можно починить, например, так:

```
print(re.search(f'{str_find}'+r'_\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}', str1))
```

Вывод:

```
<re.Match object; span=(0, 17), match='NUMBER_2021-05-01'>
```

Comment: `f'{str_find}'` - тогда уж просто `str_find + r'_\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}'`

Answer (score 3):

В качестве альтернативы можно экранировать фигурные скобки в регулярном выражении в "f-строке":

```
>>> print(re.search(f'{str_find}_\d{{4}}-\d{{2}}-\d{{2}}', str1))
<re.Match object; span=(0, 17), match='NUMBER_2021-05-01'>
```

Comment: Это полезно знать, но в целом идея экранирования меня бесит, особенно если много чего нужно экранировать. Когда можно обойтись без экранирования, это прекрасно )

Comment: @CrazyElf, в случае с регулярками я бы тоже сделал как у вас в ответе)

Answer (score 1):

Есть еще старый вариант подстановки через `%`, который сработает в этом случае:

```
print(re.search('%s_\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}' % str_find, str1))
```